# One-way Chi-Square goodness of fit and Cramér's V

Tags: chi-squared-test, association-measure

Would it make sense to apply a measure of association test like Cramér's V on a 1xk table?

I am a bit puzzled because in the literature phi and Cramér V are normally used on 2x2 or bigger contingency tables, but while I was looking for some more info, I found the following statement on Wikipedia:

"Cramér's V may also be applied to goodness of fit chi-squared models when there is a 1×k table (e.g.: r=1). In this case k is taken as the number of optional outcomes and it functions as a measure of tendency towards a single outcome."

No reference is provided though. What do you think about it? Could you please give me some bibliographic reference?

Comment: Since the section you describe has been there since the initial creation of the article by [Tal Galili](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/253/tal-galili)  you might try contacting him (that link gives a link to his blog, at which in turn you can find a contact email under 'Contact me') and asking him firstly what it even means to have association within a single variable, how he intends the computation to be done, and for a reference (if there's no citation, it should probably be removed from the article as original research) - generally, if a person says something, ask them what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question in 2014, the information has been removed from the Wikipedia article. If you read the [discussion page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Talk%3ACram%C3%A9r%27s_V&oldid=698170726#goodness-to-fit), the person who originally added this information mentions that they didn't have a reliable source for it. I assume this addition was made at a time when Wikipedia had more relaxed rules for contributing.

If you are strictly looking for a bibliographic reference, the *R handbook* [mentions it](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_03.html#_Toc120455612). But my guess is that this reference itself relied on the Wikipedia article or on [discussions about it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110600/cram%C3%A9rs-v-for-one-variable) on CrossValidated. If it's the case, it's a bit circular and does not really answer your implied question of where this variant of Cramér's V is originally coming from.

An unknown origin does not automatically mean it doesn't have some merits, but if your question is about using an effect size with a known origin, you have several other options. There is the classic [Cohen's $\omega$](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Effect_size&oldid=1159322505#Cohen%27s_omega_(%CF%89)), which is quite useful for power calculation. It varies between 0 and a maximum value depending on the situation. Otherwise, there is the effect size *Fei* ([Ben-Shachar et al., 2023](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/11/9/1982)) and two other effect sizes for the chi-squared and likelihood-ratio tests called $E_{\chi^2}$ and $E_L$ ([Johnston et al., 2006](https://doi.org/10.2466/pms.103.2.412-414)). These three effect sizes are always bounded between 0 and 1, contrary to $\omega$.