# What is the advantage (if any) of using Cohen's $\omega$ instead of Cramer's V for effect size?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, effect-size, cramers-v

I'm wondering why I should or should not use Cohen's $\omega$ (omega) for effect size over Cramer's V for a chi-square goodness-of-fit test?

What would be the advantage or disadvantage of favoring Cohen's $\omega$?

I am using the rcompanion package with the cohenW() and cramerV() functions.

Comment: You are using a chi-square goodness-of-fit test , not a chi-square test of association ?

Comment: Yes, I am using chi-square goodness-of-fit test in this case.

Comment: Why would Cramer's V make sense in goodness of fit? It's for measuring association in 2x2 tables.

Comment: @glen_b you discussed this almost 10 years ago here :) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110600/cram%C3%A9rs-v-for-one-variable This "variant of Cramér's V" seems to come from the Wikipedia article in its original 2011 version (after looking around, I couldn't find any reference older than that). The only implementation of this variant I'm aware of is in the R library `rcompanion`. I guess that calling it "Cramér's V" may be considered a misuse of language; as far as I can tell, it isn't Cramér who proposed this adjustement to the V coefficient for the case of one-dimensional tables.

Comment: Yes, as discussed there, that's not actually Cramer's V, it's just somewhat related/analogous to it. I agree with your assessment of the circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mention that you're using the *variant** of Cramér's V in a goodness-of-fit scenario, in the case of equally-distributed expected frequencies, one advantage of the $V$ variant over Cohen's $\omega$ is its upper bound of 1. So you can see how far the effect size is from its maximum possible value. There's the same advantage in the case of a contingency table, where $V$ is a measure the association between two variables. As noted in Cohen, J. (1988). *Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences* (2nd ed.) (in the case of $\omega$ used as a measure of association in contingency tables):

> Although $\omega$ is a useful ES index in the power analysis of contingency
> tables, as a measure of association it lacks familiarity and
> convenience

I think that the same remark holds for Cohen's $\omega$ in the case of a one-dimensional table, not just contingency tables.

Note that Cohen's omega has also an upper bound of 1 in the case of two categories (which implies $\omega=V$, see the penultimate paragraph below) with expected proportions of 0.5. But in other cases, $\omega$ maximum possible value exceeds 1, so it might be difficult to interpret.

On the other hand, Cohen's $\omega$ allows you to directly use it for power calculation - again, see Cohen (1988).

In cases other than equally-distributed expected frequencies (always in the situation of a one-dimensional table), as the variant of V can exceed 1, it loses its only advantage. You might have some context-dependent advantages (e.g. if you're more familiar with one coefficient than the other, or if you're trying to compare studies using the same coefficient) but I don't think this is generally a massive advantage – though I'd be happy to be corrected here. As Cohen's $\omega$ is generally the effect size that software ask you as an input in the context of power analysis (see the [pwr library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/vignettes/pwr-vignette.html) for example), for any pratical purposes it's probably more relevant to use it than the $V$ variant in unequally-distributed expected frequencies.

As a side note, you might be interested by the fact that $\omega = V\times\sqrt{k-1}$, where $k$ is the number of categories used in the Cramér's V formula, so converting one to the other is quite straightforward.

You might be also interested by the Pearson contingency coefficient (C)  and by the Fei coefficient (פ), that are bounded between 0 and 1. If you refer to the [R effectsize library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effectsize/index.html), they can be used as an effect size measure in the case of a one-dimensional table. You can find formulas for these two coefficients in the [documentation of the  *effectsize* library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effectsize/effectsize.pdf), page 5. The Fei coefficient is also explained more thoroughly in [this 2023 article](https://doi.org/10.3390/math11091982) by Ben-Shachar et al.

The *effectsize* library authors recommend using *Fei* over Cohen's $\omega$ and Pearson's C for reasons [explained here](https://easystats.github.io/effectsize/articles/xtabs.html#goodness-of-fit) (i.e. they claim that Cohen's $\omega$ and Pearson's C are inflated, but I'm not sure what they mean exactly by this, and the article by Ben-Shachar et al. doesn't seem to tackle this specific point).

---

* calling it "Cramér's V" is probably a misuse of language, as this variant for one-dimensional table doesn't seem to have been proposed by Cramér. After looking around, the origin of this $V$ variant is unclear to me. After re-reading Cohen's book discussion on $\omega$ and $V$ (pp. 216-224), it seems that Cohen implicitly excludes the use of $V$ for one-dimensional tables. See [Cramér's $V$ for one variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110600/cram%C3%A9rs-v-for-one-variable) for some additional discussion on the use of the $V$ variant on one-dimensional tables.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, neither Cohen's *w* nor Cramér’s *V* is routinely used for a goodness-of-fit test. (***Edit:*** see the comments following this answer.)

Cramér’s *V* can be modified for use in a goodness-of-fit test.  If the theoretical proportions for the test are all equal, Cramer's *V* is relatively easy to interpret.  It's more difficult to interpret if the proportions are not equal.

Considering a test of association, Cramér’s *V* is a popular effect size statistic, and has the advantage of being confined to the range of 0 to 1.

Cohen's *w* doesn't have this quality, and may have popularity simply because it was presented by Jacob Cohen (*Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences*, 1988) and is used there in power analysis.

Comment: See also, in the test of association context: [www.researchgate.net/post/Whats_the_reason_for_deriving_Cohens_w_from_Cramers_V_if_the_latter_is_already_a_measure_of_effect_size](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Whats_the_reason_for_deriving_Cohens_w_from_Cramers_V_if_the_latter_is_already_a_measure_of_effect_size)

Comment: Thanks. I was mainly going off Table 1 in Cohen (1992):
https://web.mit.edu/hackl/www/lab/turkshop/readings/cohen1992.pdf

Comment: Interesting.  For readers, the article recommends Cohen's *w* for a chi-square goodness-of-fit test. ... I think the dispositive difference, then, is that Cramer's *V* is constrained to the range of 0 to 1, which, to me, is a desirable characteristic. ... It appears that Cohen's *w* will tend to result in a larger value.

Comment: As a software note, in the *rcompanion* package, it appears that the *cohenW()* function works fine if the vector of observed counts is passed to it.  For Cramer's *V*, the *cramerVFit()* function needs be used in the goodness-of-fit case.

Comment: Thanks for all your support with this. Really appreciate it.